Health Connect Permission Request Problem on Android 13 and below
The Health Connect permission view does not open on API < 34. It doesn't crash, if I click the button nothing happens. What is the problem?
val permissionRequestContract = PermissionController.createRequestPermissionResultContract()

val permissionsLauncher =
    rememberLauncherForActivityResult(
        contract = permissionRequestContract
    ) {
            ....
      }

Permissions are granted:
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.health.READ_STEPS" />

    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.health.READ_WEIGHT" />

    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.health.READ_BODY_TEMPERATURE" />

    <queries>
        <package android:name="com.google.android.apps.healthdata" />
    </queries>
</manifest>

Launched:
Button(
    onClick = {
        permissionsLauncher.launch(REQUIRED_PERMISSIONS)
    },
) { 
    ...
  }

Permissions:
val REQUIRED_PERMISSIONS = setOf(
    HealthPermission.getReadPermission(BodyTemperatureRecord::class),
    HealthPermission.getReadPermission(StepsRecord::class),
    HealthPermission.getReadPermission(WeightRecord::class)
)


Go to AndroidManifest.xml and make sure that the relevant activity has the following intent-filter added:
<intent-filter>
    <action android:name="androidx.health.ACTION_SHOW_PERMISSIONS_RATIONALE"/>
    <category android:name="android.intent.category.HEALTH_PERMISSIONS"/>
  </intent-filter>

See details
